# socket.io not working node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am not able to run socket.io code in node.js, console.log() is also not displaying when running the code. Below is the code.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.post('/testStream',test.testStream);
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

module.exports.appServer = server;
```

and I have created a test.js file where I am accessing this exported variable appServer.

```
var server = require('../app.js');

exports.testStream = function(req,res){        
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server.appServer);
    io.on('connection',function(socket){
        console.log("in socket");
        fs.readFile('E:/temp/testimg.png',function(err,buf){
            socket.emit('image',{image: true,buffer: buf});
            console.log("test image");
        });
    })       
}
```

when the code runs it stucks and not showing the console.logs(). What I am doing wrong over here. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @cbass, This line is already there in the code. Can I update the question?

Comment: http createServer is not sync, so when you export that module, that server is not initiated, try and make that code to be async, by using process.nextTick()

Comment: @Tim, Thanks. Can you please guide me with some example? That would be really helpful for me.

Comment: hey, the main problem here u export the wrong variable from app.js, u check the doc socket.io, u are suppose to export the http.createServer(app), u binding the wrong var

Comment: @Tim, Isn't I am giving the value to var server ? I guess this should work var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

Comment: Do you have front end? cause io.on('connection') will be called only after socket client connected by using io.connect() function on client side.

Comment: @user840250, I am calling through rest client by calling a service /testStream

Comment: why not u try to write everything in one file, and then seperate into modules?, i tested ur code just now, but i not sure which socket.io version u are using, u need to follow the style of initializing the socket.io server from their webpage

Comment: @Tim the version is socket@1.3.5. I will give a try what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following the code structure as suggested in socket.io docs.

Also, you should **not** be calling `io.listen` or `io.on('connection')` inside your `testStream` express middleware. These are things you should only be doing once, and ideally they should happen during startup, inside app.js and not in reaction to a POST request. In fact, I'm not sure what the purpose of your `testStream` middleware is, its not even returning any response (eg `res.end()`)

If you want to handle socket connections in a separate module you can, but instead of exporting your app's `server` the way you are, try passing the `io` instance as variable to your submodule. In short, try this:

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var test = require('./test')(io);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**test.js**

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("in socket");
        fs.readFile('E:/temp/testimg.png', function(err, buf) {
            socket.emit('image', {
                image: true,
                buffer: buf
            });
            console.log("test image");
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: the purpose of testStream service is to provide a image/video byte stream to a client side(i.e is device). I am able to send the byte stream through streams(in base64), but while reading more I came to know i.e sending byte stream through socket is more efficient. If you can give me more idea how to send the video byte stream to the device in more efficient way it would be great help to me?

Comment: Discussing that here in this comment section would be of little discoverable use to other stackoverflow users. I would suggest you try googling something along the lines of "node video stream" and trying out what you find. If you do encounter any specific issues and need help you can always post a new question.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have posted a question about this few days back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234622/best-approach-to-send-byte-stream-in-node-js-to-client-side